# Pandas lookup by pd.Interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains numeric intervals (pd.Interval), e.g. age intervals, and some value associated to it. Now, given an age I want to lookup the value in the corresponding age interval.

An example of such a dataframe can be obtained as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age'    : [ int(random.random()*20) for x in range(50) ],
    'values' : [ random.random() for x in range(50) ]
    })

df['Age10bin'] = pd.qcut(df['age'],10)
aggdf = df.groupby('Age10bin').agg({'values' : { 'Avg_values': 'mean', 'Count': 'count'}})
```

```
              Avg_values Count
Age10bin
(-0.001, 1.9]   0.701276     5
(1.9, 3.0]      0.556729     6
(3.0, 6.0]      0.675447     5
(6.0, 10.0]     0.441387     7
(10.0, 11.0]    0.407906     4
(11.0, 12.0]    0.171417     4
(12.0, 14.0]    0.471452     5
(14.0, 15.0]    0.087788     5
(15.0, 17.1]    0.499927     4
(17.1, 19.0]    0.413713     5
```

So now say I have an age X: I want to retrieve the 'Avg_values' for the age bin containing X.

I tried the following:

```
aggdf.loc[ (aggdf.Age10bin.left <= X ) & ( X <= aggdf.Age10bin.right), : 'Avg_values'].max()
```

But it tells me that ""'Series' object has no attribute 'left'"". I also tried comparing without .left or .right but it tells me that I cannot compare scalar and categorical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First slightly change the way you create your `aggdf` to make sure there is no multiple index in `columns`

```
aggdf = df.groupby('Age10bin')['values'].agg({ 'Avg_values': 'mean', 'Count': 'count'})
```

Then we using `.loc`

```
aggdf.loc[10]
Out[378]: 
Avg_values    0.548805
Count         5.000000
Name: (9.3, 12.2], dtype: float64
```

Comment: Seriously!? Sometimes pandas is more intelligent than I expect. Is there a way to make it work also when the bin is a normal column and not an index?

Comment: @lucapescatore then we just do `isin`  `df[df.Age10bin.isin([10])]
`

Comment: On thanks this will do I think. Last question: I actually have groups on multiple fields, not just 1. So Age and Country for example. How would you do this indexing on multiple fields? Using it as a column I could do df[ (df.Age10bin.isin([10])) & (df['Country']=='UK') ] I suppose but maybe it's not the best way. Is there a way to do it using the index method?

Comment: @lucapescatore simple fix df.reset_index(), then apply your above condition , then we just slice the df .

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
aggdf.loc[19, ('values', 'Avg_values')]
```

which gives you (for data generated by `random.seed(10)`):

```
0.3641232022211824
```